# WPF Bind to Parent's SelectedItem's Property From BasedOn

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles

I have the following style:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabPanelBorderBrush" Color="#007ACC"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Style="{DynamicResource TabPanelScrollViewer}">
                                <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" Panel.ZIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Button x:Name="AddTabItem" Content="&#xE109;"  Style="{DynamicResource TabControlButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TabPanelBorder" Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="TabPanelBorderRectangle" Fill="{DynamicResource TabPanelBorderBrush}" Height="2"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource TabControlBackground}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to bind the TabPanelBorderRectangle's `Fill` color to the `TabControl`'s `SelectedItem`'s `Foreground`.
So I wrote the following:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="TabPanelBorderRectangle" Fill="{Binding SelectedItem.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Height="2"/>
```

**And it works.**

Now, I have another style, `BasedOn` the above.
In the `BasedOn` style, I want to put the line above, but when I do it doesnt work.

Here's my BasedOn Style:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomizedMetroTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:MetroTabControl}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabPanelBorderBrush" Color="{Binding SelectedItem.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

When I change the `Color` to anything else (green, blue etc...) it works.
Whats the problem with my binding? why it doesn't work in the `BasedOn` style but it does in the original?

Comment: `TabControl` no where lies in Visual Tree of the brush. If you look at the output window, you will see binding errors over there.

Comment: There are no errors, it just not working. I understand what you mean, how can I fix it? how can I bind to the TabControl if the brush isnt in the visual tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Change value of Element's Property from BasedOn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032874/wpf-change-value-of-elements-property-from-basedon)

Comment: Not duplicate. in the previous question I wanted to understand how to change the value from the BasedOn. here I want something different - I want to understand how to bind the SolidColorBrush to the TabControl from the BasedOn. Not even close to my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny how you say that you didn't have an errors in the Output Window in Visual Studio because when I added your code to a new project and ran it, I got the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Foreground; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=16700594); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Of course I swapped your `local:MetroTabControl` for a plain old `TabControl`, but the error would have been the same. You're getting this error because you have a `TabControl` that is looking for a property on *another `TabControl` that is an ancestor of this one*.

Had you tried to use the `TemplatedParent RelativeSource Binding` that you used on the `Rectangle` in the `ControlTemplate` you would have go the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Foreground; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=56437836); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

This error is more helpful because it basically tells you that you can't access an element from a `ControlTemplate` from outside that template, or more accurately as Rohit mentioned in his comment, you can't access an element that is not in the connected visual tree.

So, to answer your question, your `TemplatedParent Binding` worked in the main `Style` not because it was simply in the main `Style`, but because it was in the `ControlTemplate` in the `Style`. Therefore your `BasedOn` `Style` didn't work because it was not in the `ControlTemplate`. If you had defined the `ControlTemplate` again in your `BasedOn` `Style` then it would have worked, but clearly you wouldn't want to do that.

A better idea to fulfil your requirement would be to `Bind` the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` property to an `int` property in your view model and then `Binding` to that same `int` property and use a simple `IntegerToColorConverter` for your `Rectangle.Fill` property.

Comment: I dont know why, but I just dont get the errors. I have no reason to lie about that. anyway I understood the way to fulfill my requirement but the the whole point was not to build anything specific to fulfill it... I will just redefine the ControlTemplate and it will solve the problem. I am not sure if its the right solution here, but clearly the easier one...

Comment: @Ron, in Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings and set Data Binding to a level of `Warning` or higher and then you should see the errors in the Output Window.

Comment: It was set to warning, and yet I didnt get the error.. The style is defined inside Generic.xaml of Custom Control Library, maybe thats the reason?

Comment: That's strange... you *should* still get warnings/errors from XAML in generic.xaml.