# Using BasedOn and Trigger to manipulate nested property in parent Style

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a file of standard styles. One style, `SectionGroup`, we use on all our GroupBox elements. It has a custom template which uses a Border to put an underline below the header, among other things.

On one page, we have a checkbox next to a GroupBox header; when the user unchecks the checkbox, the contents of the GroupBox hide (visibility collapsed) and the header remains. Unfortunately the underline under the header then looks ugly; we also want to hide this.

I've given it my best attempt, so the parent `SectionGroup` style now looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SectionGroup" TargetType="GroupBox">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="HeaderBorderThickness">0,0,0,1</Thickness>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
        <Grid Margin="0">
          ...
          <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="{DynamicResource HeaderBorderThickness}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox}}"/>
          </Border>
          ...
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

By defining the `HeaderBorderThickness` resource and using it as a DynamicResource, I can override it in my page ([as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20033791/47493)):

```
<GroupBox>
  <GroupBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource SectionGroup}">
      <Style.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="HeaderBorderThickness">0,0,0,0</Thickness>
      </Style.Resources>
      <!-- TODO triggers here.. -->
    </Style>
  </GroupBox.Style>
  <GroupBox.Header>Section One</GroupBox.Header>
  ...contents...
</GroupBox>
```

So indeed, by redefining a Thickness of the same key, the `DynamicResource` works as expected and there is no underline on the header.

Now I need to toggle it based on a trigger/binding. I'm pretty new to this, but elsewhere in this page I have figured out to do stuff like this:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=FooBoolean, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}">
```

I think there's a little more magic involved in our viewmodel class (followed the example of existing bindings & properties), but it works.

Now the question is -- how do I bind the boolean value in `FooBoolean`, to the `HeaderBorderThickness` resource value? Or what other means can I use to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could do this in a much more WPF way with a `DataTrigger`, perhaps something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=
        GroupBox}}"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Height="1" Margin="0,2,0,0" Fill="Black">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{IsChecked, ElementName=YourCheckBox}" 
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Rectangle.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

This method enables you to set the `Width`, `Height`, `Padding` and whatever other properties of the line. If you can't access the `CheckBox` directly from the `Style`, then you could try adding a `bool` property to bind to both the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property *and* the `DataTrigger.Binding` property. Or just manage the `Rectangle.Visibility` in your own method.

Comment: I'm trying to connect the dots as to how your example applies to the snippets I gave... So you would suggest adding a nested style to the Border element inside the SectionGroup style, and then how would I bind to the specific checkbox on the section of the page that is using this style and needs the checkbox? SectionGroup is in a xaml file used by many views, so I can't just bind it to a checkbox. It's used for every 'section' of our app.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it looks like you're only using the `Border` element for the underlining... I'm suggesting using a `Rectangle` instead. You could use a `BoolToVisibilityConverter` instead of the `DataTrigger` as well. As I said, *you could try adding a bool property to bind to both the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property and the `DataTrigger.Binding` property*. Do you have any base view model? You could put it in there, so all the views would have access to it. Make sure it's `static`, or put it in a Singleton class.